# MySql Division between the sum of column by week and sum column by week in another table

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables, Table A and Table B

```
 Table A Structure
 ItemCode   Amount         DatebyDay
 01         1000           20170821
 01         1000           20170822
 01         1000           20170823
 01         1000           20170824
 01         1000           20170825
 ...
 02         2000           20170821
 02         2000           20170822
 02         2000           20170823
 02         2000           20170824 
 02         2000           20170825
 ...
 03
 ...

 Table B Structure
 FieldCode   Amount         DatebyDay
 fd        10000          20170821
 fd        10000          20170822
 fd        10000          20170823
 fd        10000          20170824
 fd        10000          20170825
 fd        10000          20170826
 ...
```

I would like have a SQL which can   1. Sum every item's amount by week.   2. Sum field fd's amount by week.  3. divide 1 value with 2 value at the same week.
My expected result is

```
 WeekNum  ItemId  DividedResult
 33
 34         01     0.1                      //(1000*5)/(10000*5)
 34         02     0.2                      //(2000*5)/(10000*5)  
 34         03     ...
 35
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT WEEK(DatebyDay),SUM(A.Amount),SUM(B.Amount),SUM(A.Amount)/SUM(B.Amount) FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.ItemCode=SUBSTR(B.FieldCode,3,LENGTH(B.FieldCode)) AND A.DatebyDay=B.DatebyDay
GROUP BY WEEK(DatebyDay);
```

You can try above code.

**NOTE:** Here i am considering both table are related with each other like **`ItemCode`** is substring of **`FieldCode`**.

Comment: Thank you@Sagar. There is no related with each other on ItemCode and FieldCode. Sorry for my vague and indefinite. I revised my expression.

Comment: I revised your sql to ： SELECT Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode, SUM(a.amount),SUM(b.amount),SUM(a.amount)/SUM(b.amount) 
FROM  a
INNER JOIN b ON b.code='fd' AND a.datebyday=b.datebyday
GROUP BY Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode. It wordks. Thank you!

Comment: Great..!!
Keep It up..!!

Comment: @Sargar sorry bother you. My new problem related to this question is suppose there are  2 different FieldCode in table B, fd1 and fd2. If I want to sum the value of fd1 and fd2 first. then sum the itemcode 01 in table A, and divide the two value. How should I update the SQL you suggested? I tried the following ,but obvious isn't right.     SELECT Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode, SUM(a.amount),SUM(b.amount),SUM(a.amount)/SUM(b.amount) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (b.code='fd1' OR b.code='fd2') AND a.datebyday=b.datebyday GROUP BY Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode.